# JQuery setting background color in multistate field

Tags: jquery, html, forms

In a form field I wish to have 4 different colors for the 4 field states: idle, on focus, valid and invalid.
The concept is to have a relaxing color for a never touched field, a neutral color as soon the field is entered, and later a good / nogood color depending on validity, while user is typing.
Right now, the 2 validity colors are handled by CSS with input:required:invalid {..} ...
I don't know how to prevent the coloring when the field is still empty.
Furthermore, if I set this function:

```
$('.fieldBack').on('focus', function () {
    this.style.background=colorIdle;
});
```

the field is correctly set to white (colorIdle) when entered, but then it stays white regardless of actual validity, as if the HTML5 checking is lost.
I'm quite confused.

Comment: Can you provide a working example? jsfiddle/snippet/codepen

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want to do:

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qLnrcdod/5/)

**Javascript**

```
var colorIdle = 'lightblue';
var colorFocus = 'lightgreen';
var colorFilled = 'green';
$( "input" ).focusin(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', colorFocus)
});

$( "input" ).focusout(function() {
  if($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).css('background-color', colorFilled)
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', colorIdle)
  }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="formPro" action="">
  Required input <input type="text" required> <br/>
  Normal input <input type="text">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
input {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qLnrcdod/5/

Comment: This is part of what I need. It is missing the HTML5 validation (I use 'required' and 'pattern') . I already did something similar, but when the user enters the field ('focus') and type something the colors associated with HTML5 valid / Invalid do not appear anymore. In other words, your 'colorFilled' should be replace by the 'colorValid' or 'colorInvalid' defined in CSS and selected by HTML5. In the meantime I'm testing then CSS 'input.focus.required.valid..' solution @ Dekel Unfortunately I do not know and use Fiddle (I should study it !) to show what I get.

Comment: @Orionis You can play with `input:valid`and `input:invalid` properties then, I will make another solution for you now :)

Comment: @Triyer Quite good! II was already on that way and your fiddle helped me. Just for clarity, one source of troubles in my testing was due to Foundation6 which sets its own classes on input fields types, sometimes in contrast with what I needed.

Comment: @Orionis I'm happy then ;)